# Is it okay to fill NaN values before running StandardScaler?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I have a [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) dataset in which some columns contain NaN values. For each column that contains NaNs, I also have corresponding columns that have 0 or 1 values to denote whether the column with NaN is "active", and it's always 0 (to denote that the column is "inactive" for that row) whenever there's a NaN value. scikit-learn's [`StandardScaler`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) won't run on a dataset that includes NaNs; since I have the columns that denote active/inactive, is it okay to just use the [`pandas.DataFrame.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) function to change all the NaN values to 0?

Comment: Can you describe more your data ? How many samples and features do you have ? A bother idea could be to replace NaN with the mean of the corresponding column instead of filling with 0s

Comment: Adding to @sera 's comment, scikit-learn has Imputer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer.html#sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer) which you can try to use to fill NaNs with most probable or mean values of that feature.

Comment: And if you want to know if filling NaNs with a different value, or 0 as you want, then I think you should ask this question on [Cross-validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) to find out the pros and cons of this.

Comment: Thank you for your responses -- I appreciate it -- but the size and shape of my data is irrelevant. The point is that I have boolean columns in the same dataset that (ideally) tell a learner whether the column or columns in question are even "active", and their value is `false` whenever there is a NaN value. That's why I'm pretty sure it's okay to simply replace the NaNs with zeros, but I am hoping for someone to confirm as such. That's also why I don't think it would make sense to use the `Imputer`, because there's no sense in inserting fake data if the learner can simply ignore that feature.

Comment: Just dont use those "inactive" columns in learning then.

Comment: That's not really a palatable option, though, unfortunately, because then I lose all the possible learning from the rows in those columns that don't have NaNs.